# Importing rails-assets.org stylesheets from SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bundler, bower, sprockets

Is it possible to import a stylesheet from a rails-assets.org gem using scss's `import` instead of sprocket's `require`? For example:

Given this `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem "rails-assets-RRSSB"
```

Using a sprockets stylesheet, normally you'd use a `require` in `application.css` (working):

```
*= require RRSSB/scss/rrssb
```

However, I'm using SCSS and would like to use `import` in `application.css.scss` (not working):

```
@import "RRSSB/scss/rrssb";
```

Comment: Have you tried `@import "RRSSB"` or `@import "rrssb"`?

Comment: Yep @dinocarl, no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your rvm gem directory (`rvm gemdir`) and look for the gem `rails-assets` pulled (`/gems/rails-assets-YOUR_GEM-VERSION`).
2. In the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory find your file.
3. Import/require the file with the path relative to `app/assets/stylesheets`.

The same goes for javascripts (in `app/assets/javascripts`).

This worked for me with `rails-assets-bootstrap-sass-official`, the file I was trying to import was `bootstrap-sporckets` and it was (including all other files) under `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sass-official` so my import was:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/bootstrap-sprockets"
```